# Dell 15 7559 Turns Off Randomly

Tags: laptop, memory, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7559, everything went well until I upgraded memory from 8GB to 16Gb (2x8gb).

After I did that, my computer started to "get buggy".

1. First, it didn't want to turn on, I remove the CMOS Battery and put it again to reset BIOS, and then it worked fine. But it last approximately just like 3-5 months.
2. Then, again, the computer didn't want to turn on. Again, I remove the CMOS battery, but it didn't work this time. Sometimes, the computer turned on, passed the BIOS, but immediately the OS started it turned off. I had clues it might be because of a deficient power supply, so I noticed battery was expanded and also Dell laptops has this ePSA software pre-boot who showed me Error about Battery can not supply enough power. I removed the battery so now, my computer just starts with the original power charger adapter
3. I cleaned my computer to make sure dust or some dirty stuff could be the problem, and thanks that (I think) my computer turned on again without any “boot problem”. I am a Windows 10 user because of my apps, but I have Ubuntu installed too. So, now, randomly once the OS starts Windows 10 shows me a BSOD with the code WHEA UNCORRECTABLE ERROR. In Ubuntu, occurs something similar, after the OS starts Ubuntu just freezes like for 20 seconds and then it restarts. Basically I can't do a thing, because this happens like 5 - 10 minutes after the desktop appears in both OS.
   A thing I noticed, when a I did a Diagnostics in the ePSA Dell software, is that every time I want to make a test to the memory, the computer immediately turns off and restart. It doesn't show me any error in other hardware piece, nor CPU or GPU.

I remove the expanded RAM, and left the computer with the original one 8gb, because I think maybe the other RAM stick was bad. So then, I run MEMTEST86 in a USB for a whole night and at the next day it shows no errors. Then I run the MEMTEST86 who is installed by default in Ubuntu without the USB and it freezes, just one second after the Test has started.

I'm stuck and I don't know what could be the real problem of all this. The RAM? The RAM Sockets? THE CPU?

I thought it could be a failure with the heatsink or something with high temperatures, but I don't think so, because in Windows sends me BSOD and not shutdown immediately, and in Ubuntu, it freeze for a little time before it restart.

I attach some indicators about the temperature and RPM of my fans.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Get the Dell Diagnostic Support app for your machine. Download it, run it, and see what hardware errors it points to. Memory is part of its diagnostics. Log into the Dell Support site with your service tag.

You should be able to get it for a bootable USB key so that you can run it independently of the operating system.

This will help you do an initial determination between hardware (it does appear to be hardware) and operating system issues.

Comment: HI! Thanks for answering. Sorry, i did not find the Diagnostic Support app you are talking about. I searched, but i couldnt find it. In the oficcial Support Dell Page just appears the pre-boot ePSA only. But as I said, when the test starts inmeddiately shutdown once it starts with te Testing Memory Progress.

Comment: Try this  Reboot your computer and press the f12 key as soon as you see the Dell screen that shows right before the Windows...
Now you should see the black boot menu screen. From here it depends on which model of computer you have, but the...
Use the up/down arrows to select “Diagnostics” or “Utility Partition” or something similar and press the enter key.    From   https://nccumc.org/it/faq/how-to-run-hardware-diagnostics/#:~:text=%20How%20to%20Run%20Dell%20Computer%20Hardware%20Diagnostics,can%20%28these%20tests%20aren%E2%80%99t%20important%20now%29.%20More%20

Comment: Thanks, for your comments! Yeees! That's what I do! That's the ePSA software I'm talking about  I run the test but when starts testing the memory "Testing Memory in Progress", the computer shutdown, it no shows error, just immediately, in a blink, make the computer turns off. That didn't happen before, and it's just with the memory, I can select differents piece of hardware to test like CPU, WLAN, GPU or BATTERY and the test ends well, without errors, but just with MEMORY happens this, as soon as I click in Run Test for MEMORY it shutdowns.

Comment: So at this point, replace the memory or get the computer serviced by a local dealer.

Comment: I've bought a new ram memory and try it into the two sloth my laptop has. It keeps doing exactly the same. I'm worried about the motherboard slots can be the problem. There's a way to know if they truly are the problem?

Comment: I would get an estimate for repair from a local repair person as I suggested earlier.